# Is my method for finding the Basis for the Row(A) correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

> $$A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&2\\3&2&0\\0&1&3 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Find a basis for $\text{Row} (A)$

$$Row(A)=\text{span} \left[\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}\right]$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&3&0\\0&2&1\\2&0&3 \end{pmatrix}$$

Upon performing Reduced Row Echleon Form (RREF)

I get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&-3&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

The first and third column has a pivot so the basis must be the corresponding vectors so therefore:

$$\text{basis:  } Row(A)=\text{span} \left[\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}\right]$$

**Is this flawless, and is there a faster method? Anyway I can improve my answer?**

Comment: The second matrix you wrote is not in reduced row echelon form but in row echelon form and is not row equivalent to $A$.

Comment: @levap what do you mean by not row equivalent to A? Btw is my answer wrong?

Comment: The final answer is correct, but I don't understand what you did. What does it mean "upon performing reduced row echelon form"? On what matrix did you apply row operations to bring it to reduced row echelon form?

Comment: @levap ops forgot to mention that. See my edit :)

Comment: Well, then it is correct but much too complicated. Instead of performing row operations on $A$, you performed row operations on $A^t$. The row space of $A$ is (up to transpose) the column space of $A^t$ but row operations on $A^t$ does not preserve the column space so you have deduced which columns of $A^t$ are linearly independent from which columns of the reduced row form of $A^t$ are linearly independent. This is a very convoluted argument.

Answer (score 1):

Elementary row operations preserve the row space of $A$ (but change the column space). If you want to find a basis for $\mathrm{row}(A)$, perform elementary row operations on $A$ until you reach the reduced row echelon form. The non-zero rows of the reduced row echelon form will form a basis for $\mathrm{row}(A)$. In fact, you don't even have to perform row operations until you reach the reduced row echelon form - you can stop whenever it is clear what is the basis for $\mathrm{row}(A)$.

In your example,

$$ \left( \begin{matrix} -1 & 0 & 2 \\ 3 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 \end{matrix} \right) \xrightarrow{R_1 = (-1) \cdot R_1} 
  \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & -2 \\ 3 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 \end{matrix} \right) \xrightarrow{R_2 = R_2 - 3R_1}
  \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 2 & 6 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 \end{matrix} \right) $$

and from the last matrix it is already clear that

$$ \mathrm{row}(A) = \mathrm{span} \{ (1, 0, -2), (0, 1, 3) \}. $$

If you want to find the column space of $A$, you can do the same with column operations (which preserve the column space but change the row space).

Comment: +1 :) is my method wrong btw?